Removing animation from CALayer
I'm currently building a drawing app that should leverage a CALayer hierarchy to avoid redrawing each layer when not necessary (e.g. I would like to render temporary stuff like selections on a separate CALayer without re rendering the actual drawing).
My problem is that I can't find a way to disable the implicit animation of the CALayer.
In this sample code I render a + at the mouse position, and as I move the cursor I can see the old + fading out as you can see here
class LayerViewAppKit: NSView {
    
    let myLayer = MyLayer()
    var mousePos : CGPoint!
    var trackingArea: NSTrackingArea?
    
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
        
        self.layer = myLayer
        wantsLayer = true
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        print("not implemented")
    }
    
    override func updateTrackingAreas() {
        super.updateTrackingAreas()
        
        if let trackingArea = trackingArea {
            removeTrackingArea(trackingArea)
        }
        
        let options: NSTrackingArea.Options = [.activeAlways, .mouseMoved]
        trackingArea = NSTrackingArea(rect: bounds, options: options, owner: self, userInfo: nil)
        addTrackingArea(trackingArea!)
    }
    
    override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        let mousePos = convert(event.locationInWindow, from: nil)
        myLayer.drawLines(at: mousePos)
    }
    
}

Here is the custom layer implementation
class MyLayer : CALayer {
    
    var pos : CGPoint?
    
    override func draw(in ctx: CGContext) {
        
        guard let pos = pos else {return}
        
        ctx.setStrokeColor(.black)
        let vline = NSBezierPath()
        vline.move(to: .init(x: 0, y: pos.y))
        vline.line(to: .init(x: bounds.width, y: pos.y))
        vline.lineWidth = 2
        
        let hline = NSBezierPath()
        hline.move(to: .init(x: pos.x, y: 0))
        hline.line(to: .init(x: pos.x, y: bounds.height))
        hline.lineWidth = 2
        
        ctx.addPath(vline.cgPath)
        ctx.addPath(hline.cgPath)
        
        ctx.strokePath()
    }
    
    func drawLines(at pos : CGPoint){
        self.pos = pos
        setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    
}

How can I remove every kind of animation from the CALayer?
I tried putting the drawing code inside the following:
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)
//drawing code
CATransaction.commit()

and also tried with myLayer.removeAllAnimations() in different places with no success.

Do not subclass CALayer without a copy implementation.

@matt Why is this important for my problem? I tried implementing a copy function but this has no effect. Also tried providing a delegate instead of subclassing with no success

I don't know whether it is important for your problem. But it's important.

To avoid animations, you need to implicitly tell the layer transaction to disable all animations, and then commit the changes.
CATransaction.begin()
CATransaction.setDisableActions(true)

// Set your new values here

CATransaction.commit()

